# session variables lost when the computer is suspended

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, setinterval, suspend

I have some session variables in a asp.net aplication. I have created a periodic function in Javascript with setInterval, to keep the session active (and the variables).
The problem comes when the computer is suspended, because this periodic function stops running and when the user returns the session has expired.

I need to conserve these variables even if the computer is suspended.

One of the variables that I need to conserve is a matrix.

Here is the declaration:

Dim matrixFTS(300, 1) As String

Comment: Why not set the session to never expire? It solves both your problem and not loading the server with useless traffic.

Comment: If the server doesn't have interaction during that time, the session expires.  There's nothing you can do except extend the session timeout in the web.config, which may also be overridden by the IIS machine.config.  Alternatively, you can persist your important stuff to a database instead of RAM.

Comment: Use a database to store your information, or some JSON file. And make sure you have the right pc to return the info to, USE COOKIEs ;).